# Highcharts - remove times between dates on a datetime xaxis type

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I'd like to make it so that only dates, not times, are displayed as labels on my Highcharts chart. How can I do that?

[image]

[Here's an example jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Cople/5emac/)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code & markup inline in your question.

Comment: Could you describe your problem inside the question, please? I took some time loading the image and figuring out what the difference was 

Comment: sorry, i'm not good in english.here, how to remove the labels in red. http://i.imgur.com/NQhBm.png

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you should set the [xAxis.minTickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minorTickInterval)

```
xAxis: {
        minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
}
```

[jsFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/bv9ED/)
[jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/5emac/1/)

I highly encourage going through the vast and useful [highcharts api reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) before posting questions

Comment: This works for months if you multiply the above by 28 days (to cover for February) - at least it works on ranges of 3 years or less. I am concerned that because every month has a different number of days, that the tick interval of 28 days might cause the month names to go out of alignment - but so far I haven't seen a problem.

Comment: Can this be achieved without specifying tick intervals ? The reason being, for smaller date ranges you will see hours show up, but when the date range is huge (for ex 1 year) then the no of ticks are automatically reduced.

Comment: @Naveen you can try out http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPixelInterval or tickAmount or tickPositioner for a complex and dynamic positioning

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/type-datetime/