# Highcharts - Setting minRange independent of series, range

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart that's dynamically populating multiple series (3). The x-axis is plotting datetime, value, so the data point looks like this -

['02/20/2013 13:35PM', '55']
['02/20/2013 13:45PM', '75']
['02/20/2013 14:15PM', '65']
['02/20/2013 15:25PM', '85']

The problem is that for a month's worth of data, we're getting approximately 50 data points, which means the x-axis has 50 labels. Is there a way to set the minRange so it's only a day, and there's one label on the x-axis for each day, but multiple points on the graph?

When I set minRange = 86400000 it makes the report grind to a halt and freezes the browser, even with 30 data points.

Help? Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: I've tried this -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447771/highcharts-remove-times-between-dates-on-a-datetime-xaxis-type
For some reason it only plots one date, at the start of my x-axis.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YMWRm/5/

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the dates as strigs. You need to specify your x values as UTC numbers in order for highcharts to create sensible xAxis labels for dates and times.

Try specifying your data like this:

```
[Date.UTC(2013,01,20,13,35,00),55],[Date.UTC(2013,01,20,13,45,00),75], etc.
```

This converts the dates to UTC dates (milliseconds since 1st Jan 1970). Note, javascript months go from 0 to 11.

If you specify your data like this, you can tell highcharts to use date time logic on the xAxis like this:

```
xAxis: {
    type:"datetime"
}
```

Comment: I'm actually parsing the JSON Date returned from my webservice using the following -
function formatJSONDate(jsonDate) {
            var newDate = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
            
            return newDate;
            }

Comment: Oddly enough now when I return the date as above, all I get is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... in the x-axis. I think you're onto something.

Comment: Also converted it to Epoch Milliseconds... No dice.

Comment: Could you recreate you example in jsfiddle.net? Because SteveP's answer is correct, but probably the problem is with parsing your data. Because Date.UTC() returns date in timestamp. Your jsonDate is 
['02/20/2013 13:35PM', '55'] ['02/20/2013 13:45PM', '75'] ['02/20/2013 14:15PM', '65'] ['02/20/2013 15:25PM', '85']
or looks like different?

Comment: I can't get it to run in JSFiddle... :-/
Here's my code though -
http://jsfiddle.net/YMWRm/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YMWRm/5/ 
It now works in JSFiddle, if you look at my example you'll see I'm still converting to a JSDate but the minrange doesnt work.